# NPE when Java method is called second time after mockup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I want to implement JUnit 5 test in order to test services:

***JPA Repository:***

```
@Repository
public interface RiskFilterRepository extends JpaRepository<RiskFilters, Integer> {
    .....
}
```

***Service Interface:***

```
public interface RiskFilterService {
    ......
}
```

***Service implementation:***

```
@Service
@Qualifier("riskFilterService")
@Transactional
public class RiskFilterServiceImpl implements RiskFilterService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private RiskFilterRepository dao;
    ...
}
```

***Service for testing:***

```
@Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("riskFilterService")
    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

    public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(Terminals terminal) {  
       this.terminal = terminal;
    }

    public void validateBinCountryCheckFilter() throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {

        List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(terminal.getId(), "BinCountryCheckFilter");
    }
}
```

***JUnit test***

```
    public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest    {

        @Autowired
        private RiskFilterRepository repository;

        @BeforeEach
        public void beforeEachTest() throws IOException {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
        }

        @Test
        public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {
           // this mock is working fine
           BDDMockito.given(riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(anyInt(), anyString())).willReturn(riskFiltersList);

           // this mock is working fine - I don't get NPE
           List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(11, "BinCountryCheckFilter");

           // this mock is working fine
           BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilterImpl = new BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(terminal);

           // I get NPE here 
           binCountryCheckFilterImpl.validateBinCountryCheckFilter();
        }    
    }
```

I get NPE error when I run the JUnit code for this Java method `validateBinCountryCheckFilter()`.

```
List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(11, "BinCountryCheckFilter");
```

So the first when I run the code with `BDDMockito.given....` the mocked SQL query `riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType....` is working fine. 
But after that second time when I run `binCountryCheckFilterImpl.validateBinCountryCheckFilter();` I get NPE for the code `riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType....`

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure about *BDDMockito*, but in some frameworks you need to mock the results of consecutive calls separately: `.willReturn(riskFiltersList).willReturn(riskFiltersList)`.

Comment: Most likely the subject under test is not using the mock. And since the dependency is not assigned, you get a NPE. Why not explicitly inject it into the subject as done with terminal.

Comment: Where are the mocks? Where do u get riskFilterService from in the test? Why are you not injecting dependencies by constructor?

Comment: Indeed, what @Nkosi said... Where is that `terminal` in `BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilterImpl = new BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(terminal);` defined?

Comment: @ZeroOne Terminal it's just a Java Object.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the subject under test is not using the mock. And since the dependency is not assigned, you get a NPE.

Why not explicitly inject it into the subject via constructor injection as done with terminal.

```
@Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;
    private Terminals terminal;

    @Autowired
    public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(Terminals terminal, RiskFilterService riskFilterService) {  
        this.terminal = terminal;
        this.riskFilterService = riskFilterService;
    }

    public void validateBinCountryCheckFilter() throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {

        List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(terminal.getId(), "BinCountryCheckFilter");
    }
}
```

That way the mock can be explicitly injected when testing

```
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest    {

    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {
        //Arrange
        RiskFilterService riskFilterService = Mockito.mock(RiskFilterService.class);
        Terminals terminal = Mockito.mock(Terminals.class);

        BDDMockito.given(
            riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(anyInt(), anyString()))
            .willReturn(riskFiltersList);

        int expectedInt = 11;
        String expectedString = "BinCountryCheckFilter";

        when(terminal.getId()).thenReturn(expectedInt);

        BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilterImpl = 
            new BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(terminal, riskFilterService);

        //Act
        binCountryCheckFilterImpl.validateBinCountryCheckFilter();

        //Assert
        then(riskFilterService)
          .should()
          .findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(expectedInt, expectedString);
    }    
}
```

Comment: It's working working but there is a way I don't want to send `RiskFilterService` as a argument of the constructor in order to keep the design of the Service clean. Is there some other way?

Comment: @PeterPenzov How are you supposed to provide mocks of you can't inject them?

Comment: Good question - I'm not aware. Other ideas?